# How to remove the 'hover dropdown' effect on Blogger main menu and have primary words clickable?

Tags: html, templates, blogger

I'd like to get some help with the HTML in a template I've just installed on my new Blogger site. The main MENU is obviously set up to be a 'hover dropdown' style menu, but I don't want it to be, I just need the main words to be clickable. At the moment you need to hover below or above the main words (using 'freebies' as an example) in order to click it. (Which is strange) How can I make it so that it clicks on the actual word 'freebies'. Side note: the responsive mobile version of this page works just fine. Any help is really appreciated! Website is here: picketandvine.com

And here is my code for the menu bit I think. Sorry, I'm not very learned in this!

```
-----------------------------------------------
Blogger Template Style
Name:        Glam Up
Author :     http://www.soratemplates.com
License:     Free Version
----------------------------------------------- */


/* Global reset */
/* Based upon 'reset.css' in the Yahoo! User Interface Library: 
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui */
*, html, body, div, dl, dt, dd, ul, ol, li, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, pre, 
form, label, fieldset, input, p, blockquote, th, td { margin:0; padding:0 }
table { border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0 }
fieldset, img { border:0 }
address, caption, cite, code, dfn, em, strong, th, var { font-style:normal; 
font-weight:normal }
ol, ul, li { list-style:none }
caption, th { text-align:left }
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { font-size:100%; font-weight:normal }
q:before, q:after { content:''}

/* Global reset-RESET */
strong { font-weight: bold }
em { font-style: italic }
a img { border:none } /* Gets rid of IE's blue borders */
body#layout, body#layout .container {
width:800px;
}
body#layout #header {       
margin-bottom: 80px;
clear:both;
}
body#layout #main {
width: 55%;
margin-right: 0;
}
body#layout #widget-area .widget, body#layout #sidebar .widget {
width: 100% !important;
}
body#layout #navigation {
height: auto;
margin-bottom: 60px;
margin-top: 30px;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
z-index: 999999;
}

body#layout #navigation-wrapper {
width:40%;
float:left;
}
body#layout #top-social {
float:right;
}
body#layout #widget-area .footerwidget {
width:250px;
 margin-right: 20px;
}
body#layout #widget-area .widget, body#layout #sidebar .widget {
width:250px;
}

body {

background-color:#fff;

color: #444;
font-weight: 400;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
font-size: 14px;

word-wrap: break-word;
font: normal normal 14px Georgia, Utopia, 'Palatino Linotype', Palatino, 
serif;

margin: 0;
font-weight: 300;
-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
color: #404040;
letter-spacing: .07em;

}

p {
font-size:14px;
line-height:26px;
}

a {
text-decoration:none;
color:#cea525;
}
a:hover {

}
a.quickedit img {width:18px!important;height:18px!important;}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
font-family:"Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

.container {
width:1160px;
margin:0 auto;
}
.container.sp_sidebar {
overflow:hidden;
margin-top: 50px;
}

#main {
width:100%;
}

.container.sp_sidebar #main {
width:790px;
margin-right:30px;
float:left;
}
#sidebar {
width:320px;
float:right;

}

/********************************/
/*** Navigation ***/
/********************************/

#navigation {
background:#171717;
height:50px;
position:fixed;
z-index:999999;
width:100%;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;

}

.slicknav_menu {
display:none;
}   

#navigation .container {
    position:relative;
}

.menu {
float:right;
}

.menu li {
display:inline-block;
margin-right:22px;
position:relative;
}

.menu li a {
font-family:"Open Sans", sans-serif;
font-size:11px;
font-weight:400; 
letter-spacing:2px;
color:#fff;
line-height:50px;
text-transform:uppercase;
display:inline-block;
-o-transition:.3s;
    -ms-transition:.3s;
    -moz-transition:.3s;
    -webkit-transition:.3s;
}

    /*** DROPDOWN ***/

    .menu .sub-menu,
    .menu .children {
        background-color: #171717;
        display: none;
        padding: 0;
        position: absolute;
        margin-top:0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 99999;

    }
.menu li .sub-menu li ul{
    left: 100%;
top: 0;
background: #383838;
display: block;
position: absolute;
z-index: 10;
visibility: hidden;
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transition: all .25s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all .25s ease-out;
-ms-transition: all .25s ease-out;
-o-transition: all .25s ease-out;
transition: all .25s ease-out;
}
    ul.menu ul a,
    .menu ul ul a {
        color: #999;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 6px 10px 7px 10px;
        min-width: 160px;
        line-height:20px;
        -o-transition:.25s;
        -ms-transition:.25s;
        -moz-transition:.25s;
        -webkit-transition:.25s;
        transition:.25s;
        border-top:1px solid #333;
    }

    ul.menu ul li,
    .menu ul ul li {
        padding-right:0;
        margin-right:0;
    } 

    ul.menu ul a:hover,
    .menu ul ul a:hover {
        color: #fff;
        background:#333;
    }

    ul.menu li:hover > ul,
    .menu ul li:hover > ul {
        display: block;
    }
.menu li .sub-menu li:hover > ul {
visibility:visible;
opacity:10;
display:none;
}

    .menu .sub-menu ul,
    .menu .children ul {    
        left: 100%;
        top: 0;

    }

body#layout div#sidebar {
width: 270px;
}


.menu1 {
text-align:center;
}
div#navigation-wrapper1 {
border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.menu1 li {
display:inline-block;
margin-right:35px;
position:relative;
}

.menu1 li a {
display: block;
line-height: 50px;

color: #7e7e7e;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 500;
font-family: Raleway;
font-family: Lato;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: 600;
letter-spacing: 2px;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: #222222;
}

    /*** DROPDOWN ***/

    .menu1 .sub-menu,
    .menu1.children {
        background-color: #171717;
        display: none;
        padding: 0;
        position: absolute;
        margin-top:0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 99999;

    }

    ul.menu1 ul a,
    .menu1 ul ul a {
        color: #999;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 6px 10px 7px 10px;
        min-width: 160px;
        line-height:20px;
        -o-transition:.25s;
        -ms-transition:.25s;
        -moz-transition:.25s;
        -webkit-transition:.25s;
        transition:.25s;
        border-top:1px solid #333;
    }

    ul.menu1 ul li,
    .menu1 ul ul li {
        padding-right:0;
        margin-right:0;
    }

    ul.menu1 ul a:hover,
    .menu1 ul ul a:hover {
        color: #fff;
        background:#333;
    }

    ul.menu1 li:hover > ul,
    .menu1 ul li:hover > ul {
        display: block;
    }

    .menu1 .sub-menu ul,
    .menu1 .children ul {   
        left: 100%;
        top: 0;

    }
```

Comment: What you have tried so far? post code.

Comment: Thanks. I havn't been game to try too much. I've tried adding this symbol '>' in the lines where it says 'menu ul li' etc. But that didnt help. I originally changed the whole menu to float right too. (It used to be float left but it was underneath the top social icons. Does that help a bit? Sorry, Im not a coder! :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to blogger Setting and click Template, Thank Edit Template find menu that's you want to change than remove drop down menu class code and add simple `<li>` tag. 
hopefully this helpful for you if you have any question send me some screenshot and code i'll help you more
thank You

Comment: Thanks very much but there seem to be many <li> tags, I've just added the code to my post. Does this enable you to have a better look for me? Thanks again!!

Comment: And I'd really like to keep all the 'responsive' elements of the code because it works all fine on a mobile browser. It's only the desktop code I need to change.

Comment: Use inspect tool it's help you great selecting required <li> tag